# AMD ProRender 3.0.8 crashing on final render - 2.91.2

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, radeon-prorender-render-engine

I am trying to use a Radeon RX570 in a Razor Core EGPU on a Mac. I was having constant crashing issues with it both in viewport and rendering. I have found a solution for the viewport problem by turning off the "OpenGL Interoperability" setting. However, I am still getting a crash when I try to render out a final result. Does anyone have a solution? I am using the latest version of both Blender and ProRender.